# Function unable to run multiple time

Tags: c, function, linked-list, structure

below is the function that I called to read the file and store to my linked list

```
void getList(struct List **head)
{
  struct List *navigator = *head;
  FILE *fptr;

  fptr = fopen("list.txt", "r");

  for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i ++)
  {
    struct List *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct List));

    fscanf(fptr, "%d %s %s %s %d %d %d %d\n", &temp->id, temp->name, temp->type, temp->desc, &temp->point1, &temp->point2, &temp->point3, &temp->point4);

    if(navigator->next == NULL)
      navigator->next = temp;
    else
    {
      while(navigator->next != NULL)
        navigator = navigator->next;

      navigator->next = temp;
    }
  }

  rewind(fptr);
  fclose(fptr);
}
```

below is the struct List i build

```
struct List
{
  int id;
  char name[30];
  char type[6];
  char desc[7];
  int point1;
  int point2;
  int point3;
  int point4;
  int point5;
  struct List *next;
};
```

i call the function to read the data below

```
1 cabbage vege green 1 2 3 4
2 cucumber vege green 2 4 6 8
3 celery vege green 3 4 5 6
```

this function worked when run the 1st time but it will comes out with error when i run it second time, and i m sure the first time it able to read all the data.
Why and how to improve it?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? How are you calling the function?

Comment: i am using a online compiler and it just exit with status -1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you use an online compiler, are you sure that it is able to read the file `list.txt`? It sounds more like a compilation problem to me.

Comment: You need to post `struct List` definition and sample data read.

Comment: You forget to set `temp.next= NULL;`

Comment: You don't appear to deal with the situation of `navigator` being `NULL` either

Comment: it seems like doesn't work too when `navigator` contains value